# Query many to many with Sequelize in Nodejs/Express application

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm building a Nodejs/Express backend with MySQL and Sequelize, and I'm struggling with the syntax of querying through the relationships.

I have a Category table, a Media (images) table, and a join table MediaCategory. I have a REST route that includes a Category ID, I want to fetch all the Media entries for that selected Category.

I have the models defined, and the following definitions in app.js

```
Media.belongsToMany(Category, {
  through: {
    model: MediaCategory,
    unique: false
  },
  foreignKey: 'category_id',
  constraints: false
});

Category.belongsToMany(Media, {
  through: {
    model: MediaCategory,
    unique: false
  },
  foreignKey: 'media_id',
  constraints: false
});
```

And my getCategoryImages controller method is this:

```
exports.getCategoryImages = (req, res, next) => {
  const categoryID = req.params.category;
  console.log("const categoryID: ", categoryID);

  Category.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: Media,
      where: {
        id: categoryID
      }
    }]
  })
    .then(categoryImages => {
      if (!categoryImages) {
        const error = new Error('Could not find categoryImages.');
        error.statusCode = 404;
        throw error;
      }
      res
        .status(200)
        .json({
          message: 'Fetched category images successfully.',
          items: categoryImages,
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    });

};
```

The response I get in Postman for the URL localhost:8080/categoryImages/16 is this:

```
{
    "message": "Fetched category images successfully.",
    "items": []
}
```

There are dozens of image records that should be returned in the items array.

I'm afraid I'm struggling to understand the syntax for fetching through the join table, and I'm hoping someone can point me to where I'm off the rails.

Comment: should `where: { id: categoryID }` be outside of include? (media doesn't have the categoryID?)

Comment: That was part of the solution - thank you! I also had the foreignKeys reversed in the belongsToMany definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as it turns out, was that I had the foreign keys reversed in the two association definitions in app.js

```
Media.belongsToMany(Category, {
  through: {
    model: MediaCategory,
    unique: false
  },
  foreignKey: '*media_id* not *category_id*',
  constraints: false
});

Category.belongsToMany(Media, {
  through: {
    model: MediaCategory,
    unique: false
  },
  foreignKey: '*category_id* not *media_id*',
  constraints: false
});
```

Media uses 'media_id' as the foreign key, and Category uses 'category_id', not the other way around as I had tried initially.

As well, as Emma pointed out in the comment above, the `where: { id: categoryID }` block needed to be outside the include.

```
 Category.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: Media
    }],
    where: {
      id: categoryID
    }
  })
```